# Getting callback data from WebView Android

Tags: android, webview, chromium

I am using a webview to submit a form and redirect. When the form is submitted successfully it will print a json response to the console.

My question is how can I get the jsonData String from the client?

chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Callback....jsonData, etc"

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // Insert your code here

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the WebViewClient class and create a method to intercept the POST request made from clicking the form post button in the HTML in your WebView.  Then, make the HTTP POST request in the code, rather than in the WebView and parse the results anyway you wish, then refresh the WebView any way you wish at the end of it all.  There is an example of doing so here:

https://github.com/KeejOow/android-post-webview/blob/master/PostWebview/postwebview/src/main/java/com/solidsoftware/postwebview/InterceptingWebViewClient.java

Comment: Note, in the example I linked to above, their implementation of the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method is only valid for Android SDK levels below, 24.  You would probably want to implement both the old version, and the new version that uses WebResourceRequest request instead of String url as the second parameter.